# Joomla Template and Foundation 5 Framework

Tags: joomla, zurb-foundation, joomla3.2

I have created a basic template  for Joomla using [Foundation 5 Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) but the call to include Foundation and jQuery and the call to fire Foundation needs to be the last part that is loaded.

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/app.js"></script>
```

So I have added them into the template and they can be navigated to when I load the template up but for some reason foundation does not exist according to firebug and won't load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If Firebug is saying that the file does not exist then you have used the incorrect path. As for the importing of jQuery, I would recommend you use the Joomla standards for this which will also import the file that comes package use `noConflict()` mode like so >> `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`</strike>

Also try using the `addScript()` method for importing your other scripts, however please ensure that the paths are correct. So your full code will look like this:

```
<?php
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
    JHtml::_('script',  JUri::root() . 'templates/template_name/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js');
    JHtml::_('script',  JUri::root() . 'templates/template_name/js/app.js');
?>
```

Currently, your `.js` files are within the template folder, however are within different sub-folders, thus I would recommend sticking to 1 main folder for all javascript files.

**Update:**

I have just tested Foundations and it works fine for me. First of all, you need to ensure that jQuery is loaded first. Add the following code before the ending ` tag in your template index.php file:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script> $(document).foundation(); </script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Many thanks for coming back to me.  I have tried your suggestion and it adds the reference to each JS file in the head and not the footer before the closing </body>.  Also the files exist and I can view the source but the last include to app.js invokes a call to foundation and firebug reports that that function does not exist when it clearly does because I can view the source from the rendered page.  Any clues?

Comment: Ahh you need to appended before the ending body tag, wasn't aware of this. I will download foundation and do a test myself in a bit and come back to you on that :) May I suggest that you in the mean time upgrade to Joomla 3.2 ;)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear I am working with version 3.2 on my local mac test environment.  many thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @GrahamCole - I have updated my answer and have fully tested it. Works like a charm for me on Joomla 3.2 ;)

Comment: Many thanks for coming back to me.  I must be missing a trick here.  I am still getting the same issue on the mac test environment which may probably mean that foundation isn't loading at all.  Do you have any thoughts on this?  I will try this on my live environment tonight to see if I can get it to work there.  Cheers for all your help. Graham

Comment: Hmm that is rather odd. If you like, you could send me the template zip so I can install it on my localhost, get it set up, then send it back to you. Here is my email address if you like: lodder15@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: @GrahamCole - I've sent you an email